# Python Dictionary error list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary below, but trying to get a list of movies with IMDB score greater than 5, but keep getting the error ' list indices must be integers or slices, not str'

```
movies = [{

"name": "Usual Suspects", 
"imdb": 7.0,
"category": "Thriller"
},
{
"name": "Hitman",
"imdb": 6.3,
"category": "Action"
},
{
"name": "Dark Knight",
"imdb": 9.0,
"category": "Adventure"
},
{
"name": "The Help",
"imdb": 8.0,
"category": "Drama"
}]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please when asking a question here, always try to paste the code you have used, that's help to understand, and most time, how to fix the problem. (here is the problem us well understood)

Answer (score 0):

Classic way:

```
# lst = []
for movie in movies:
    if movie['imdb'] > 5:
        print (movie['name'])
        # lst.append(movie['name'])
```

Output:

```
Usual Suspects
Hitman
Dark Knight
The Help
```

With list comprehension:

```
print ([ movie['name'] for movie in movies if movie['imdb'] > 5 ])
```

Output:

```
['Usual Suspects', 'Hitman', 'Dark Knight', 'The Help']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of dictionaries..Try the following code

```
movies_with_good_rating = []
for movie in movies:
    if int(movie.get('imdb')) > 5:
       movies_with_good_rating.apppend(movie.get('name'))
print(movies_with_good_rating)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of dicts. Output needed is list of movies with Imdb greater than 5. Try the below code.

```py
    movies_list = []
    for dictionary in movies :
        if dictionary["imdb"] > 5:
            movies_list.append(dictionary["name"])
    print(movies_list)
```

Output:

```py
    ['Usual Suspects', 'Hitman', 'Dark Knight', 'The Help']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is classic

```py
for i in range(0,len(movies)) :
    if movies[i]["imdb"] > 5:
        print (movies[i]['name'])
```